# Creating a Color Display Application with user inputted RGB 0-255 integers converted to hex

Tags: javascript, html, function, colors, user-input

I'm new at working with HTML/Javascript, and I am having great difficulty with creating a color display application that is supposed to do the following in HTML/Javascript:

1. Color button reads input values, converts RGB integer values to hex, assign the hex to
2. Fill button fills entire  with current color
3. Outline creates a 10px wide border at the edge with current color from 1
4. Clear fills entire canvas with #000000
   Edit: I got the Fill() function to color my canvas. How would I split this between the Color() so that it assigns the value to the canvas?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <body>
    <form>
    <input id = "red" type = "number"  min="0" max="255">Red</input>
    <input id = "green" type = "number" min="0" max="255">Green</input>
    <input id = "blue" type = "number" min="0" max="255">Blue</input>
    </form>
    <br></br>
    
    <button id="btnC" onclick = "Color()">Color</button>
    <button id = "btnF" onclick = "Fill()">Fill</button>
    <button id = "btnO" onclick = "Outline()">Outline</button>
    <button id ="btnCl" onclick = "Clear()">Clear</button>
    <br></br>
    
    <canvas id="cva" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#000000;"></canvas> 
    <br></br>
    <p id = "display"></p>
    
    </canvas>
    
    </body>
    
    <script>
    
    
    document.getElementById("btnF").addEventListener("click", Fill);
    function Fill() {
        //Input rgb value
    let rValue = document.getElementById("red").value;
    let gValue = document.getElementById("green").value;
    let bValue = document.getElementById("blue").value;
        //process rgb string
    let rgbString = "rgb(" + rValue + "," + gValue +"," + bValue +")";
        //output display rgb
    document.getElementById("cva").innerHTML=rgbString;
    document.getElementById("cva").style.background=rgbString;
    }
    document.getElementById("btnC").addEventListener("click", Color);
    function Color(){
    let displayC=document.getElementById("cva").innerHTML=rgbString;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=rgbString;
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("cva").style.backgroundColor=color;

should work.

Also look here:

[https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/add-styles-to-an-element/][1]